# Which KL Divergence is larger D(P|Q) or D(Q|P)?

Tags: normal-distribution, information-theory, kullback-leibler

From the perspective of information theory, I understand how D(P|Q) is non-negative and why the KL divergence is asymmetric, i.e. $D(P|Q) \neq D(Q|P)$, given two gaussian univariate gaussian distributions.

I also know that 
$D(P|Q) = ln\frac{\sigma_q}{\sigma_p} + \frac{\sigma_p^2 + (\mu_p - \mu_q)^2}{2\sigma_q^2} - \frac{1}{2}$

My question is that if the mean of both the divergence is equal, i.e. $\mu_p = \mu_q$, Which of the divergence would be larger, D(P|Q) or D(Q|P)?

Comment: Hi Inderpartap, welcome! Do you have an idea of how to check the sign of $D(P|Q) - D(Q|P)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the ratio of deviations. Let $x=\sigma_p/\sigma_q$ When $\mu_p=\mu_q$, $$D(P|Q)=-\ln x+x^2/2-1/2, D(Q|P)=\ln x+{1 \over 2x^2}-1/2$$
As you might guess, these two are equal when $x=1$ and there is no other solution because if $x=a$ is a solution, so as $x=1/a$; and for $x>1$, this expression is greater than $0$, i.e. there is no zero-crossing.

To sum up, $D(P|Q)$ is larger when $\sigma_p>\sigma_q$.